# How to change value in dictionary to None if key is identical to value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a bunch of files I'm creating dictionaries from and in some of the files the key and value I'm creating are identical. I need to keep track of the dictionaries that are identical so another person can update them with the right values.  I'd like to set the value for these dictionaries to none.  I've already stripped all whitespaces and weird characters so the key and value are exactly identical.  I basically want to say, "if the key and value are identical, then set value = None"...

```
x = file I'm creating dictionary from
if x[1] = x[4]:
    d[x[1]] = None
```

But whenever do anything like this I get a an error message:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Right off the bat `=` should be `==` when comparing `x[1]` and `x[2]`

Comment: You are obviously creating the dict so all you need to change is what Rafael suggests, `if x[1] == x[4]:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python (and in all other languages I know), for comparing the value in `if`, double equals `==` is used. I'll suggest you to read: [Python IF...ELIF...ELSE Statements](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm). Below is the sample code, to set value as `None` where `key` and value are same:

```
my_dict = {'a': '1', 'b': 'b', 'c': '2', 'd': 'd'}  # 'b' and 'c' have same
                                                    # 'key' and 'value'
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if key == value:
        my_dict[key] = None

# Updated value of 'my_dict':
# {'a': '1', 'c': '2', 'b': None, 'd': None}
```

Comment: @e9e9s: Added the sample code for this. You will get better idea

Answer (score 2):

As i can't understand the description properly, i will answer the title :

```
for k, v in d.items():
    if k == v:
        d[k] = None
```

Comment: @pscuderi this is fine because it is iterating over the *items* (tuples), not the dictionary

Comment: @brianpck, it makes no difference, nothing is being removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dictionary comprehension for this:

```
>>> d = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 'c' }
>>> { a: None if a == b else b for a,b in d.items() }
{'a': 1, 'c': None, 'b': 2}
```

This obviously will create a copy of the whole dictionary, so the above answers are probably better for your use case.

Comment: I don't think they have a dict already , they are creating it from the file content so this is probably a better approach.